# Correct usage of "ubiquitous"

Tags: word-usage

*(Context: local middle school gave each student a personal Chromebook in September.  Letter to administrator about problems, that were not solved by opting my child out of the Chromebook three weeks ago.)*

> When M uses the Chromebook, he compulsively surfs the web.  When he
>   doesn't use it, he feels like an afterthought.  I'm starting to
>   wonder, who is more tech-addicted -- M, or the teachers in whose
>   classes the Chromebook is so ubiquitous?

Is that right? Or should I say

> ... the teachers in whose classes Chromebook usage is so ubiquitous?

Comment: It's really just a stylistic choice, but I have the impression *ubiquitous* is more likely to be used of *concrete* nouns such as *Chromebooks*. Abstract nouns such as *usage* are more likely to be ***prevalent***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Thank you.  Make it an answer and I'll accept it!  //  I really want to say "ubiquitous", "prevalent" just doesn't do it for me in this context.  I want to express the idea that it's impossible to get away from the *$(%$! things.  My son says you can't even have a conversation with someone in the cafeteria any more -- "Don't bother me!  I'm about to win this level!"

Comment: It's only my *opinion* - I'll be interested to see if others agree with it, but more importantly someone may be able to produce *evidence* (which would interest me even more, even if it conflicts with what I said). Incidentally, I don't understand what you mean by *he feels like an afterthought*.

Comment: I wouldn't use _so_ before _ubiquitous_. I would use _ubiquitous_ alone and hope that readers would understand that I was using _ubiquitous_ in the sense of "present everywhere in the defined area"—an idea that is stronger than either _prevalent_ or _so prevalent_.

Comment: @SvenYargs - good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @FumbleFingers that this is a matter of personal stylistic preference. **Both options are perfectly grammatical and correct.**

Personally, I would prefer "in whose classes the Chromebook is so ubiquitous", just because it seems punchier.

Regarding the type of nouns used with *ubiquitous*: the *CORPUS OF CONTEMPORARY AMERICAN ENGLISH* provides evidence that the **top five nouns that go after the word are abstract ones** (with "nature" obviously acting as an abstract one as well):

[image]

This is a collocation search for "ubiquitous" that includes only nouns following the target word with a distance of one.